# Simply form posting recording more database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I made a simple form. In this form, if there is a code in the database to be registered, if I do not want to be recorded but I want to record both and 30-40 times to add to the database. Where am I making a mistake?

```
<?php 
                    if(isset($_POST['guncelle'])){

                        $kadi   =   $_POST["kadi"];
                        $gpa    =   $_POST["gpa"];
                        $miktar =   $_POST["price"];



                        $Kontrol = $db->query("SELECT * FROM veriler",PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        if($Kontrol->rowCount()){
                                foreach ($Kontrol as $sorgu){
                                if($gpa==$sorgu['gpa']){
                            echo  ("<script>
                            Swal.fire({
                                type: 'error',
                                title: 'Hata!',
                                text: 'Girmiş olduğunuz kod daha önce kullanılmış!',
                              })
                            </script>");

                                }else{
                            $Kayit  =   $db->query("INSERT INTO veriler SET kullanici='$kadi', gpa='$gpa', durumu=0, miktari='$miktar'");
                            echo  ("<script>
                            Swal.fire(
                                'Good job!',
                                'You clicked the button!',
                                'success'
                              )
                            </script>");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


  ?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for general guidance and advice.

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear. What do you mean "record both and 30-40 times add to the database"? Are you looking to add an entry for each row found in your `veriler` table?

Comment: @tadman no. When ı clicked submit button normally is 1 row added but ım looking  database they added 40--50 more time like a spam.

Comment: You're running an `INSERT` statement inside a loop (`foreach ($Kontrol as $sorgu){`) so you will get multiple records this way. If you want to insert just one record you'll either need to get rid of the loop or move it outside the loop.

Comment: For example: It looks like you can make your statement more focused and avoid the loop: `SELECT * FROM veriler WHERE gpa=?` and then `bind_param('s', $gpa)` to filter out only the records with the matching conditions. Let the database do the work for you.